# I can't display videos, audio and images in Laravel PHP and HTML

Tags: php, html, laravel, audio, video

I'm learning to display media on PHP. I use the following codes to display my videos and audio in my blade.php file and run it on Apache server of XAMPP. It displays an unloaded image and an unloaded video. I also installed laravelcollective/html class to my json file.
Here are my codes:

```
<audio autoplay id="mainaudio">
   <source src="resources/views/Assets/kifflom_music.mp3">
</audio>
```

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="resources/views/Assets/video.mp4" type="video/ogg">.
</video>
```

And here is what Edge and Opera GX displayed:
[image]

, although a year ago, I run the same codes in a HTML file on Microsoft Edge and it did display the video and music, and now it displayed nothing. Don't know if the browsers don't support the  and  tags or it has some problems about cache of the computer. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check console log of your browser to see the error and find out why these resources cannot be loaded. It could be either 404, 403, 5xx, etc. (Press F12 in your browser and check **Console** and **Network** tabs)

Comment: Are you sure that the path to the files are correct?

Comment: `resources/views` is not a publicly available folder. Move the files to a folder inside the `public` folder

Comment: @Aless55 Yes, I copied by right-clicking the files and selecting "Copy Path" in PHPStorm

Answer (score 1):

Move you video and audio into public directory.

Create one directory inside **public/media**. put here your media.

then tried to link out them which below way.

```
<audio autoplay id="mainaudio">
   <source src="{{url('media/kifflom_music.mp3')}}">
</audio>

<video width="320" height="240" controls>
   <source src="{{url('media/video.mp4')}}" type="video/ogg">.
</video>
```

Comment: Still didn't work. Any other way? I've been stuck for hours. It also didn't work for normal HTML file.

Comment: did you found any error in browser console ?

Comment: There is no error. The browser can display texts, but it can't display media. Both for my PHP project and HTML project. It's getting weird.

Comment: Hello. It finally worked. It was the Edge that blocks media autoplay.